# Nginx patch method, proxy pass

Tags: nginx, proxypass, openproject

I have a small problem with nginx and **patch** method - I've got 400 Bad request.

I use OpenProject (use Apache2) in my OpenVZ.
I use Nginx on base machine and I use proxy pass to pass request to the container OpenVZ.

Unfortunetely, I have error in OpenProject - probably patch method.

How can I fix it in nginx to use patch method correctly ?

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {

    server_name DOMAIN;

    location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real_IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.130:80/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your config looks fine, did you try the same request directly to upstream?

Comment: It's wierd. I checked on another internet and it works. Maybe in public place was something blocked.